# adding next value to the object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push next value to the object saved with data() jquery method.
Right now whenever I am clicking the .fonts-container ul li,  $("#data-store").data()["text"] is just changing value, whereas I would like to add new value and preserve all the previous choices.

my buggy js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-container ul li', function(){ 
  var $el = $(this);
  var fontName = $el.data('fontname');
  $("#data-store").data()["text"] = ($el.data('fontname'));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the click callback, set the value to be an array, like `$("#data-store").data()["text"] = []`. Then the line would become:

`$("#data-store").data(["text"].push(($el.data('fontname')));`

You can then access the data in a similar way to any other array.